# SQL search strings every possible way

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, poco

Im using a DataSet with the Table 'Orders'.
There i have the TableAdapter GetDataByCustomerID() which containts this SQL:

```
SELECT        OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID
FROM            Orders
WHERE        (CustomerID LIKE @CustomerID)
```

Later im giving the Method the parameter 'Vin' for example. To find every Order with the Customer ID "VINET".

The problem is i cant get VINET by using just the string 'Vin'.

I tried:

```
 WHERE        (CustomerID LIKE '%Vin%')
```

I know this would work

```
 WHERE        (CustomerID LIKE 'Vin%')
```

but i want to be able to get the order if it containts vin. And the command 'contains' seems not to be working.

Comment: public void CustomerSelected(){
this.Orders = this.ordersTableAdapter.GetDataByCustomerID(CusID.ToUpper());
}


the method i use to get the data

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need a case-insensitive search.  It is not clear what database you are using, but one method is:

```
where lower(CustomerID) like '%vin%'
```

Depending on your database, you can also set collation explicitly to avoid case issues.  Some databases also support explicit case-independent comparison.

Comment: sry i didnt post the Method where i was already using .ToUpper